# How do I open a second window from the first window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF. I have two windows, such as window1 and window2. I have one button in window1. If I click that button, the window2 has to open. What should I do for that?

Here is the code I tried:

```
window2.show();
```

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Write your code in `window1`.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    window2 win2 = new window2();
    win2.Show();
}
```

Comment: Can I write this line on Window_Loaded event? If so, then second window is not displaying.

Comment: @Manish - as per the method name (Button_Click), put this in the click event of the Button on window1.

Answer (score 53):

When you have created a new WPF application you should have a .xaml file and a .cs file. These represent your main window. *Create an additional .xaml file and .cs file to represent your sub window.*

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Open Window" Click="ButtonClicked" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="379,264,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubWindow subWindow = new SubWindow();
        subWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Then add whatever additional code you need to these classes:

```
SubWindow.xaml
SubWindow.xaml.cs
```

Comment: simple enough! I hate wpf, it's just so uselessly complicated and designed to be counter intutive.

Answer (score 19):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    window2 win2 = new window2();
    win2.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the second window is defined as `public partial class Window2 : Window`, you can do it by:

```
Window2 win2 = new Window2();
win2.Show();
```

Comment: i want to open window2 from window1.

Answer (score 6):

This helped me:
The Owner method basically ties the window to another window in case you want extra windows with the same ones.

```
LoadingScreen lc = new LoadingScreen();
lc.Owner = this;
lc.Show();
```

Consider this as well.

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
this.Activate();
```

Answer (score 5):

In WPF we have a couple of options by using the Show() and ShowDialog() methods.

Well, if you want to close the opened window when a new window gets open then you can use the Show() method:

```
Window1 win1 = new Window1();
win1.Show();
win1.Close();
```

ShowDialog() also opens a window, but in this case you can not close your previously opened window.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a button in window1 and double click on it. It will create a new click handler, where inside you can write something like this:

```
var window2 = new Window2();
window2.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
private void OnClickNavigate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigatedWindow navigatesWindow = new NavigatedWindow();
    navigatesWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create an instance of a new window like so.

```
var window2 = new Window2();
```

Once you have the instance you can use the [Show()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [ShowDialog()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method depending on what you want to do.

```
window2.Show();
```

or

```
var result = window2.ShowDialog();
```

ShowDialog() will return a `Nullable<bool>` if you need that.