# Best way to implement a lookup table in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a page wherein there is an Employee Id field. It will lookup for the Employee table and show its result in a new form when the browse button is clicked.

I'm not sure how to implement this in WPF. Will appreciate your answers. Thanks.

[image: Employee Status]

Comment: I don't really understand what do you want to look for in the look up table? you enter employee ID and then what do you want to happen?\

Comment: @Gilad after clicking the browse button, I wanted to show a form that will list all the employee. I dont know how to do it in wpf but in webforms it's easy

Comment: you can just create a new window with the list. connect browse button to a command, have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133947/how-to-open-second-window-from-first-window-in-wpf